# side navbar when position is "Fixed"

Tags: html, css, web, navbar

I have a side nav bar and I have set the float to be right
and then when I put the position: fixed; it floated to left 
why did this happen? can anyone help me?

this is my html:

```
<div id="navbar">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="default.asp">&nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-pagelines fa-2x"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="news.asp">&nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-2x"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="contact.asp">&nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="about.asp">&nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="default.asp">&nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="news.asp">&nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-bell-o fa-2x"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="contact.asp">&nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-cog fa-2x"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="about.asp">&nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="about.asp">&nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-power-off fa-2x"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And this is my css:

```
#navbar{
position:fixed;


}
    ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:auto;
    width: 70px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    float:right;
}


li a {
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 22.2px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

li a:hover,li a:focus {
    background-color:#28a828;
    color: green;
```

}

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened because the element with `position: fixed` doesn't stretch over the entire width in contrast to the element with `position: relative`.

So you can set:

```
#navbar {
 width: 100%;
 position:fixed;
}
```

And they will work fine: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leusrox/jLc3bmk2/)

---

Another way, you can remove `float: right` in `ul`, and set for `#navbar` top/right.

This will work too: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leusrox/xm5nbrdq/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a div tag with the ID of 'content' or something like this: `<div id="content">`.

Then in CSS give it a `left-margin` or `80px` or something around that size. (I recommend using EMs instead since they scale with the web browser and work on any platform)

Your final Code should look something like this:

**Index.html**

```
<div id="navbar">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="default.asp">&nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-pagelines fa-2x"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="news.asp">&nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-2x"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="contact.asp">&nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="about.asp">&nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="default.asp">&nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="news.asp">&nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-bell-o fa-2x"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="contact.asp">&nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-cog fa-2x"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="about.asp">&nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="about.asp">&nbsp; &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-power-off fa-2x"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
<h1>CONTENT</h1>
<h1>CONTENT</h1>
<h1>CONTENT</h1>
<h1>CONTENT</h1>
<h1>CONTENT</h1>
<h1>CONTENT</h1>
</div>
```

**stylesheet.css**

```
#navbar{
    position:fixed;
}

    ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:auto;
    width: 70px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    float:right;
}


li a {
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 22.2px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

li a:hover,li a:focus {
    background-color:#28a828;
    color: green;
}

#content {
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

You can view a demo of this working here: [JSfiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvoohd0k/).

Comment: Thanks for your help:)